# Sitecore e-learning 9.0 training for certification, course 1 module 2, how to set-up the example Adventure site?

Tags: xconnect, training

I am going through Sitecore 9.0 e-learning certification training. I am on course 1 module 2.

How do you set-up the example Adventure site used in the course labs?

It looks like the student resource materials may have some of the right content but it doesn't appear to be the right file types, they are .html files whereas the e-learning approach uses ".cshtml" files, and I can't find any directions on how to include them in the project.

Are they just there for reference purpose (the lab seems to be indicating that you should be following along)?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, in one of the course PDFs: Sitecore Platform Essentials for Developer eLearning Student Lab Guide.pdf on page 23.

At the end of the previous section in the PDF (Course 1 module 1 lab) there are directions on where and what data templates to create for the next lab. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the actual course or documented anywhere, nor are you directed to follow along with the PDF lab guide, so I'm not sure how you would be expected to locate this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Sitecore 9 e-learning anymore but if I remember correctly you had to create cshtml views from those html files. Html files are there just for reference.

This is to mimic "usual" Sitecore project where at the beginning design agency prepares designs and then you are creating Sitecore renderings out of designs. Design agency outputs are usually design manual and html, js and css files.

So you start with pure html based cshtml files as renderings / views and then you are wiring this to controller and model and replace parts of html with dynamically retrieved data from some repository.

Design agencies are usually mocking the sample data. You are basically putting there correct content with this approach.